Access to google drive not being granted under a certain scenario (python api)
I am using  oauth google api to authenticate a user and the scope supplied in the request is:
"openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
The call is successful and results in a callback with the following url:
GET /auth?state=9ZA2AxPsT4afQPetOuJNg1UnBPxOaL&code=4/0AcvDMrAQaBHZpKsChV-3SzTUuV3__R83QKLmJY-ElIy-AOOaXt5P8snffxTg_-Mr8-MTAg&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%20openid%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&authuser=1&prompt=consent HTTP/1.0"
Note that the scope has 'auth/drive' included as expected and subsequent calls to perform google drive operations work fine.
From the callback request I am able to extract the associated tokens - access_token, refresh_token, etc. - and they all work. Lets call this scenario A.
However if a logged in session remains inactive for 2 weeks (it could be as few as 10 days maybe) the refresh_token becomes invalid and when a new authentication request is issued, the callback url state is missing the 'auth/drive' scope. The scope part looks like:
scope=email%20profile%20openid%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
[The app is still in a 'test mode' and refresh token being invalid is expected.]
In this scenario access to drive api is not available even though authentication succeeded. Lets call this scenario B
The outgoing authentication requests in both scenarios are identical  with the same scope; yet the scope in google api callback is missing 'auth/drive' in scenario B.
Is this a google api issue or is there something remiss in the way I am handling scopes? Any light on this is greatly appreciated.
I expected authentication (in scenario B) to allow access to google drive which it did not.
